# Cannot use GPT API on Google Collab

Tags: google-colaboratory, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I'm working on a project in Google Colab where I need to automatically generate text using pre-created prompts with the GPT-4 model from OpenAI. I wrote the following lines:

```py
!pip install openai
!pip install cohere tiktoken
import openai
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "my secret api"

response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="gpt-4", 
  prompt="hi",
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=150
)
print(response.choices[0].text.strip())
```

However, executing this code results in the following error:

> APIRemovedInV1:
>
> You tried to access openai.Completion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.
>
> You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.
>
> Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

I've looked through the OpenAI Python library documentation, the migration guide, and various resources for a solution that is compatible with Google Colab as of February 2024, but I haven't found a clear answer on how to proceed.

- I checked the official GitHub repository: https://github.com/openai/openai-python
- I reviewed the discussion and migration guide here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742
- I looked for information on using GPT-4 specifically here: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7127997-how-can-i-use-gpt-4-in-chatgpt
- I also reviewed recent commits for any clues: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/commit/86379b4471d67a9d2e85f0b0c098787fb99aa4e0?diff=split&w=1

Could someone provide guidance or an updated code snippet that works with the latest version of the OpenAI library in Google Colab?

I don't know much about it, I need a solution that works on Google Colab and is up to date as of February 2024.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use the `gpt-4` model.

If this is the case, then first of all, you're trying to use the method name (i.e., `Completion.create`), which is not compatible with the [Chat Completions API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-generation/chat-completions-api).

Change this...

```
openai.Completion.create
```

...to this.

```
openai.ChatCompletion.create
```

But if you do this, you'll still run into errors. Why?

There are still some mistakes left to fix:

- You're trying to use the method name (i.e., `ChatCompletion.create`) that works with the older OpenAI SDK (i.e., `0.28`), but not with the newer OpenAI SDK (i.e., `>=1.0.0`).
- The `prompt` parameter is not valid if you want to use the Chat Completions API. You should use the `messages` parameter instead.
- Message retrieval is different if you want to use the Chat Completions API.

See the full code with comments below.

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

response = client.chat.completions.create( # Changed
  model="gpt-4", 
  messages=[ # Changed
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ],
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=150
)

print(response.choices[0].message) # Changed
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-22-7fff54062376>", line 7
    messages=[ {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Perhaps you forgot a comma?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My bad.

Comment: it still give me error ;(
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-714a04e5d672> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "..."
      4 
----> 5 response = openai.chat.completions.create( # Changed
      6   model="gpt-4",
      7   messages=[ # Changed

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/_utils/_utils.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/openai/resources/chat/completions.py in create(self, messages, model, frequency_penalty, function_call, functions, ....

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to read this. Where exactly does error occur?

Comment: I edited my script. **Copy-paste the whole script!** What about now?

Comment: LINE : response = openai.chat.completions.create(
ERROR:
NotFoundError: Error code: 404 - {'error': {'message': 'The model `gpt-4` does not exist or you do not have access to it. Learn more: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4.', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': 'model_not_found'}}

i'm sure i have gpt-4, i use gpt's store ect..

Comment: Ah, you don't have access to the GPT-4. You need to make a successful payment of $1 or more to be able to access the GPT-4. Read [this](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/7102672-how-can-i-access-gpt-4).

Comment: I bought gpt-4 yesterday I'm sure I have it, is this different from having access to it?

Comment: Did you buy ChatGPT Plus? This doesn't count. The ChatGPT and API are billed separately.

Comment: Really? wow..
I read in the page that 
"If you're a Pay-As-You-Go customer and you've made a successful payment of $1 or more, you'll be able to access the GPT-4 API (8k)."

Comment: Yes. Pay-as-you-go is a different thing than a monthly subscription. If you bought ChatGPT Plus, you bought a monthly subscription. You're not a pay-as-you-go user.